# Instalar pyodbc Python

Tags: python, pip

Cambié de equipo y estoy instalando las librerías de Python que uso frecuentemente pero tengo problemas al tratar de instalar `pyodbc`, tengo instalado Python 3.10 y estoy usando la instrucción de correr `pip install pyodbc` pero aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el mensaje aparece la causa - 
*error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.*

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0%22. Verás otras preguntas del mismo problema.

Comment: Otra cosa: de preferencia no uses capturas de pantalla. Es mejor usar `texto formateado` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El módulo `pyodbc` incluye una extensión programada en C++. Esta extensión está compilada y disponible como *wheel* para algunos sistemas y configuraciones: https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#files

Como se ve, no hay ninguna *wheel* para python 3.10, que es la versión que estás usando.

Si no te da igual usar otra versión de python, entonces tendrás que compilar tú mismo la extensión, para lo que necesitarás *Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 o mayor*, tal como dice el error.

Por otra parte, es recomendable que instales el paquete [`wheel`](https://pythonwheels.com/) para que la creación de la extensión se haga en el nuevo formato (algo que también te indica el error).

De todas formas, si no quieres perder el tiempo compilando extensiones para windows, te recomiendo que gestiones los paquetes windows con [conda](https://conda.io).